# Discord Api Javascript String

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Ok so i made a little joke RichPresence and everything works perfectly Except the **State:** field.
**State: randomlvl,** returns an error **"State must be type string"**
So i'm guessing **State:** can't read a string type variable, it has to be "string text".
Any ideas how to make this work? How i can make **State:** read a variable pulling a random string?

```
// This template was made by FusionTerror.
const DiscordRPC = require('discord-rpc'); // Requiring the discord-rpc package.
const client = new DiscordRPC.Client({ transport: 'ipc' }); // Creating a client variable with is our rpc client.
require('dotenv').config(); // Requiring the content of our .env file.
var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
var levels = ["Hell on Earth", "Exultia", "Cultist Base", "Doom Hunter Base", "Super Gore Nest", "Arc Complex", "Mars Core", "Sentinel Prime", "Taras Nabad", "Nekravol 1", "Nekravol 2", "Urdak", "Final Sin"];

var randomlvl = Math.floor(Math.random() * levels.length);

(async () => {
    client.on('ready', async () => { // Calling the ready event.
        await client.setActivity({ // Setting the Rich Presence Activity based on what is passed in here.
            buttons: [{ label: "Steam Key Givaway", url: "https://youtu.be/Lrj2Hq7xqQ8" }],
            state: randomlvl,
            details: "Campaign (Ultra Nightmare)",
            startTimestamp: ts,
            largeImageKey: "a12e3",
            largeImageText: "Doom Eternal",
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));

        console.log("Discord Rich Presence has been enabled.");
    });

    await client.login({ clientId: process.env.applicationID }).catch(console.error); // Logging into our application.
})();
```

Comment: From your error, I think that state is expecting a String. Try `var randomlvl = Math.floor(Math.random() * levels.length).toString();`

Comment: right... math returns double.

Answer (score 0):

**solution 1:**
From your error, I think that state is expecting a String. Try `var randomlvl = Math.floor(Math.random() * levels.length).toString();` – Mady Daby 1 hour ago

**solution 2:**
`const randomlvl = str[Math.floor(Math.random() * str.length)];`